# How do I add an SVN remote to a Git repository?

Tags: svn, git

I recently used git-svn to clone an SVN repository, for the purposes of maintaining my own branch of an open-source project.

I'm also working with others on this branch, so we use a shared Git repository to help with the collaboration.

A colleague wishes to fetch new revisions from the original SVN repository. How might he accomplish this? I can simply run "git svn fetch" on my local machine, but seeing that my colleague has cloned from the shared Git repository, his local branch lacks the necessary SVN metadata for fetching.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the `.git/config` for the repo on your machine, copy the `[svn-remote "name"]` block, and have your colleague insert it in his `.git/config` :)

Comment: Good call. We just tried this, but it didn't seem to work for some reason (weird error specific to the repo.) I'll give it another try later. Thanks!